# probability of choosing points from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Six points are drawn from a uniform distribution $U(0,1)$, first 3 points are marked green, next 3 points are marked blue. What is the probability that all adjacent points are of different colour?

Answer (score 1):

All $\binom 6 3 = 20$ interleavings of colors are equally likely.  The chance that one of the two (`bgbgbg` or `gbgbgb`) you are interested in is thus $2/20 = 1/10$.

Comment: how can you say that they are equally likely?

Comment: @himanshusinghal By symmetry.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks!  I was busy and felt bad that I didn't give OP a reply.